# Building a jquery/javascript HIIT with autoplay video or image slider "playlist" using and php/mysql

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I am trying to create a countdown timer with videos. The timer needs to load data such as time for countdown, time for breaks, and number of sets the timers needs to run, video(or images in case of no video) from a MySQL table.
The timer starts counting down but needs also to start auto-playing video of image slider. When time ends starts counting down for the time break. This process continues till number of sets reached. Then it is needed to either click to go to the next countdown or after a short countdown break to load the next in queue.

I can load the data from MySQL with php and create a while loop to pass the variables need in the jQuery/JavaScript script. But i am not sure if this is the right way.

This is my approach with a bug related on clicking start/stop/reset buttons which leads to an increase of speed during countdown, and in some unwanted results regarding counting down.

A fix on that bug would be appreciated.

My code:

```js
var startTime = 10;
var restTime = 5;
var currentTime = 0;
var myTimer;
var myTimerSpeed = 1000; // 1 sec
var currentSet = 0;
var currentPause = 0;
var totalSets = 5;

resetTimer();
restTimer();

$('#pause').hide();
$('#next_exe').hide();
$('#player').show();

$('input[value="start"]').click(startTimer);
$('input[value="stop"]').click(stopTimer);
$('input[value="reset"]').click(resetTimer);

$('#currentset').html(currentSet);
$('#totalset').html(totalSets);
$('#currentpause').html(currentPause);
$('#totalpause').html(totalSets);

function resetTimer() {
  stopTimer();
  currentTime = startTime;
  $('#timer').html(currentTime);
}

function startTimer() {
  currentSet++;
  if (currentTime <= 0) {
    //resetTimer();
    startTimer();
  } else {
    myTimer = setInterval(timerTick, myTimerSpeed);
  }
  $('#currentset').html(currentSet);
}


function restTimer() {
  stopTimer();
  currentTime = restTime;
  $('#timer').html(currentTime);
}

function breakTimer() {
  currentPause++;
  if (currentTime <= 0) {
    restTimer();
    breakTimer();
  } else {
    myTimer = setInterval(timerTick, myTimerSpeed);
  }
  $('#currentpause').html(currentPause);
}


function timerTick() {
  currentTime--;
  if (currentTime == 0 && currentSet == totalSets) {
    if (currentPause < totalSets && currentPause < currentSet) {
      restTimer();
      breakTimer();
      $('#pause').show();
      $('#player').hide();
      $('#next_exe').hide();
    } else {
      stopTimer();
      //$('#myTimer').hide();
      $('#next_exe').show();
      $('#pause').hide();
      $('#player').hide();
    }

  } else if (currentTime == 0 && currentSet < totalSets) {
    if (currentPause < totalSets && currentPause < currentSet) {
      restTimer();
      breakTimer();
      $('#pause').show();
      $('#player').hide();
    } else {
      resetTimer();
      startTimer();
      $('#pause').hide();
      $('#player').show();
    }
  }

  $('#timer').html(currentTime);
  $('#currentset').html(currentSet);
  $('#currentpause').html(currentPause);
}

function stopTimer() {
  clearInterval(myTimer);

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  I want to create 2 countdowns, which can loop everytime countdown ends and a set is completed.
</p>

<div id="myTimer" style="background-color:#eee; clear:both; display:block; float:left; height:250px; width:300px; margin:0; padding:20px;">

  <div id="player" style="background-color:#333; color:#fff; font-size:14pt; clear:both; display:block; float:left; height:150px; width:300px; margin:0; padding:0;">
    <!-- embed for youtube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NlOF03DUoWc -->
    <iframe width="100%" height="150" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/gmRTQfLrbMY" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>

  <div id="pause" style="background-color:#333; color:#fff; font-size:14pt; clear:both; display:block; float:left; height:50px; width:300px; margin:0; padding:50px 0;">
    PAUSE
  </div>

  <div id="next_exe" style="background-color:#333; color:#fff; font-size:14pt; clear:both; display:block; float:left; height:50px; width:300px; margin:0; padding:50px 0;">
    Next Exercise
  </div>

  <p id='timer'></p>
  <input type="button" value="stop">
  <input type="button" value="start">
  <input type="button" value="reset">
</div>

<div id="sets" style="background-color:#eee; clear:both; display:block; float:left; height:50px; width:300px; margin:10px 0 0; padding:20px;">
  Number of Sets completed: <span id="currentset"></span> / <span id="totalset"></span>
  <br> Number of Breaks completed: <span id="currentpause"></span> / <span id="totalpause"></span>
</div>
```

Also available on [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kpmdevgr/bno5w91q/)

Suggestion of a friend:

```js
$('#pause').hide();
$('#player').hide();
$('#next_exe').hide();

function Timer(speed, duration, onTick, onComplete) {

  var speed = speed;
  var interval = null;
  var current = duration;
  var onTick = (typeof onTick == 'function') ? onTick : function() {}
  var onComplete = (typeof onComplete == 'function') ? onComplete : function() {}

  function decrement() {
    onTick(current);
    if (current > 0) {
      current -= 1;
    } else {
      stop();
      onComplete();
    }
  }

  function start() {
    if (!interval) {
      interval = window.setInterval(decrement, speed);
    }
  }

  function stop() {
    if (interval) {
      interval = window.clearInterval(interval);
    }
  }

  function reset() {
    current = duration;
    onTick(current);
  }

  return {
    start: start,
    stop: stop,
    reset: reset
  };
}

function RoundCounter() {
  var currentSet = 0;
  var totalSets = 2;
  var currentPause = 0;
  var totalPause = 2;
  var currentTimer = null;
  var mode = null;

  function initialize() {
    mode = "set";
    currentTimer = Timer(1000, 10, timerTick, completeSet);
    setupUI();
    bindUIEvents();
  }

  function setupUI() {
    $('#totalset').html(totalSets);
    $('#totalpause').html(totalPause);
    $('#currentset').html(currentSet);
    $('#currentpause').html(currentPause);
  }

  function bindUIEvents() {
    $('input[value="start"]').click(function() {
      runTimer(currentTimer);
      $('#pause').hide();
      $('#player').show();
      $('#next_exe').hide();
    });

    $('input[value="stop"]').click(function() {
      stopTimer(currentTimer);
    });

    $('input[value="reset"]').click(function() {
      resetTimer(currentTimer);
    });

    $('#sets')
      .on("timerset.complete", function() {
        updateUI();
      })
      .on("timerpause.complete", function() {
        updateUI();
      });
  }

  function updateUI() {
    $('#currentset').html(currentSet);
    $('#currentpause').html(currentPause);

    if (currentPause == totalPause &&
      currentSet == totalSets) {
      endRound();
      return;
    }

    if (mode == "set") {
      $('#pause').hide();
      $('#player').show();
      $('#next_exe').hide();
      if (currentPause < totalPause) {
        currentTimer = Timer(1000, 5, timerTick, completePause);
        runTimer(currentTimer);
      }
      mode = "pause";
    } else if (mode == "pause") {
      $('#pause').show();
      $('#player').hide();
      $('#next_exe').hide();
      if (currentSet < totalSets) {
        currentTimer = Timer(1000, 10, timerTick, completeSet);
        runTimer(currentTimer);
      }
      mode = "set";
    }
  }

  function startNextTimer() {
    if (mode == "set") {}
  }

  function timerTick(currentTime) {
    $('#timer').html(currentTime);
  }

  function runTimer(timer) {
    timer.start();
  }

  function stopTimer(timer) {
    timer.stop();
  }

  function resetTimer(timer) {
    timer.reset();
  }

  function completeSet() {
    currentSet += 1;
    $("#sets").trigger("timerset.complete");

    $('#pause').show();
    $('#player').hide();
    $('#next_exe').hide();
  }

  function completePause() {
    currentPause += 1;
    $("#sets").trigger("timerpause.complete");

    $('#pause').hide();
    $('#player').show();
    $('#next_exe').hide();
  }

  function endRound() {
    $('#myTimer').hide();
    $('#sets')
      .off('timerset.complete')
      .off('timerpause.complete');
  }

  return {
    initialize: initialize
  };
}

// on document ready, initialize everything
$(function() {
  RoundCounter().initialize();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  I want to create 2 countdowns, which can alter everytime countdown ends and a set is completed.
</p>

<div id="myTimer" style="background-color:#eee; clear:both; display:block; float:left; height:auto; width:300px; margin:0; padding:20px;">

  <div id="player" style="background-color:#333; color:#fff; font-size:12pt; clear:both; display:block; float:left; height:180px; width:300px; margin:0 0 20px; padding:0;">
    <!-- embed for youtube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NlOF03DUoWc -->
    <iframe width="100%" height="150" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/gmRTQfLrbMY" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe> VIDEO or Image Slider
  </div>

  <div id="pause" style="background-color:#333; color:#fff; font-size:12pt; clear:both; display:block; float:left; height:80px; width:280px; margin:0 0 20px; padding:50px 10px;">
    PAUSE
  </div>

  <div id="next_exe" style="background-color:#333; color:#fff; font-size:12pt; clear:both; display:block; float:left; height:80px; width:280px; margin:0 0 20px; padding:50px 10px;">
    go to next exercise
  </div>

  <p id='timer'></p>
  <input type="button" value="stop">
  <input type="button" value="start">
  <input type="button" value="reset">
</div>

<div id="sets" style="background-color:#eee; clear:both; display:block; float:left; height:50px; width:300px; margin:10px 0 0; padding:20px;">
  Number of Sets completed: <span id="currentset"></span> / <span id="totalset"></span>
  <br> Number of Breaks completed: <span id="currentpause"></span> / <span id="totalpause"></span>
</div>
```

This is also available on [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kpmdevgr/4sqheom9/)

Comment: At first glance and with the little info available, this looks like you're not properly calling `clearInterval()` on your timers when you click the stop button, or are duplicating said interval on your start or reset buttons

Comment: Your friend's code seems to work fine, are you experiencing issues with it too? Or is your question mainly about understanding why yours bugs?

Comment: @Pepper, i want to choose the right approach. I know that i only have a bug, and thank you for pointing to that direction. I had firstly started working with my code, and till know i didn't adopt friend's solution. If you run the jsfiddle you will see that although i do have a bug, i have made a more "complete" solution of what i want to achieve. What i am missing is how to apply the repeat of all those actions when first video loop ends and is time to load the next one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your timer issue comes from these lines of code:

```
myTimer = setInterval(timerTick, myTimerSpeed);
```

An interval is not really a variable, when you call `setInterval` you are creating an interval and getting in return a reference to that interval.

So if the code above is called twice, you'll have 2 intervals running but only a reference to the 2nd one, which means it will run forever and you no longer have the value needed to stop the first one.

What your friend did is to ensure there was no running interval referenced by his variable before starting a new one.

You can achieve the same result by replacing the lines above with:

```
if(myTimer) clearInterval(myTimer);
myTimer = setInterval(timerTick, myTimerSpeed);
```

And adding an initial value to your timer with `var myTimer = false;`. That should fix your timer issues

To fix transitions, I basically removed their logic from the timers start/stop functions. All transitions are now handled by `timerTick()`.

I added a `isBreak` variable to remember if we're currently in a break or set, which is then used to determine what step is next and what timer initial value to fetch.

I included two reset functions in the code (`resetAll()` & `resetCurrent()`), since I didn't know if you wanted to reset everything or only the current timer.

It should now work as follow: set -> break (5x) and on the last break, instead of `PAUSE` it displays `Next Exercise` (to which you can add a click listener calling `loadNext()` if you want the user to be able to start it manually).

In `loadNext()` you can load the images for the next exercise, and if you uncomment `startTimer()` it will start right away.

**Result:** [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gxu1pa09/1/)

Does that work as you wanted it to?

Comment: (Tip: If the edited version supercedes the original fiddle, then you can remove the original and the commentary about it not working. If you believe the OP is following along, you can add a comment about looking at the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57459370/revisions), but otherwise answers are better in a pristine condition, for the benefit of readers who have not seen it yet. You can keep it to multiple updates though if you want all of your future readers to see the progress, if there is genuine value in that.)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I didn't know about revision history either!

Comment: Marvellous, good changes, +1. You've already removed it, but I am a bit wary of promises for future updates in posts, since they are often left in for years. But it is fine if you genuinely do plan to come back and edit.

Comment: @Pepper with a small in the provided fiddle i believe it will work. The only thing ledt is the right way to implement loadNext(), i am thinking with ajax call but i will figure it out. Thanx a lot.

Comment: I have to admit that i am stuck.  I can't find the right way to use loadNext as @Pepper provided. The thing is that i want to have either multiple divs with data attributes add apply some kind of loop either use an ajax call update all the data of the current div and allow instantly to execute startTimer().
See related [https://jsfiddle.net/kpmdevgr/4h5wytkb]

Comment: I can try to help, but I'd like some precisions on what you're trying to achieve: Are you playing videos or 1 image per exercise? If it's videos, do you have the source file, or do you want to play them from a link (youtube, etc), and finally, if your workout has 3 exercises (E1, E2, E3) and 5 reps, do you want to do 5x E1, 5xE2, 5xE3 or 5x E1->E2->E3? (Also, your jsfiddle doesn't seem to exist)

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Well the videos will come from youtube. As for the part with the timings both cases can apply. That's why i do have the data-attributes on the div#player.
Now imagine either many div#player on the same page or either with the use of ajax to call the next video.
And yes i saw the issue with the link so here is the right one [link]https://jsfiddle.net/kpmdevgr/4h5wytkb

Comment: I made some [changes](https://jsfiddle.net/fhw2dL80/) but it can still be improved. It's using a single player and dynamically loading the videos between exercises, it will probably be better with 1 player per exercise, but I don't have time right now^^ (I also added timestamps in case you don't want to start at 0 in the videos)